# Does God speak in poetry in Genesis 1?

Tags: genesis, hebrew, torah, poetry

I am learning to read and speak Hebrew with the goal of being able to read the Torah, and am reading Genesis 1 (https://biblehub.com/interlinear/genesis/1.htm).

I am reading in Hebrew what God is saying aloud e.g. Gen 1:6, Gen 1:9 etc. and it seems to rhyme when I read it in Hebrew.

Is this supposed to be the case or am I imagining it? If it is poetry, of what kind?

Thanks in advance.

Max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only Hebrew poetry is Gen 1 is in V27 which is usually presented as:

> So God created man in His own image;
>
> in the image of God He created him;
>
> male and female He created them.

The rest of the text of Gen 1 does not fit the structure of Hebrew poetry.  One of the characteristics of Hebrew poetry is NOT rhyme (except by accident) - the main characteristic is repetition of thought using different words and phrases.

For more information about Hebrew Poetry see https://biblehub.com/topical/p/poetry_of_the_hebrews.htm